# Spring Data, JPQL, Group by year and month of a date column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a working native MySQL query to obtain some data by grouping up a date column by year and month (ex: 2017-01, 2017-02)

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(production.production_date,'%Y-%m') AS 'month', 
    SUM(operation.planned_quantity) AS 'planned_total', 
    SUM(operation.actual_quantity) AS 'actual_total', 
    ((SUM(operation.actual_quantity) / SUM(operation.planned_quantity)) *100) AS 'adherence' 
FROM operation 
INNER JOIN production on production.id = operation.production_id 
INNER JOIN control_point on control_point.id = production.control_point_id 
INNER JOIN work_center on work_center.id = control_point.work_center_id 
INNER JOIN cost_center on cost_center.id = work_center.cost_center_id 
INNER JOIN section on section.id = cost_center.section_id 
WHERE production.production_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00' AND '2017-05-31 23:59' 
    AND section.id = 4
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(production.production_date,'%Y-%m')
```

With this i can get the output as expected 
[the result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgBCW.png)

for now I tried two days to get this result into my spring boot project. Tried named native query, stored procedure and method signature patterns. but failed in every try. at last I had to discard changes using my git client.

Things I am trying to achieve is group by partial date, map result to custom Pojo or obtain row MySQL result in to spring app.

Please help me in this.

- Is there a way to group by partial date in JPql like "GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(production.production_date,'%Y-%m')" in MySQL, if yes an
  example please?
- How to obtain row MySQL result as a list or related from native query in spring data?
- Any example on how to map stored procedure result to a custom POJO in spring data?

**-------------------2017-06-07---------------** 
**Problem Solved**  
I managed to achieve the requirement by mixing MySQL function **DATE_FORMAT(xxx,'%Y-%m')** in JPQL i really did not have any idea of mixing both, but it works. 
My working spring function and query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT "
        + " new com.trendsmixed.fma.dao.MonthlyScheduleAdherence(DATE_FORMAT(operation.production.productionDate,'%Y-%m'), SUM(operation.actualQuantity), SUM(operation.plannedQuantity), (SUM(operation.actualQuantity)/SUM(operation.plannedQuantity))*100) "
        + " FROM Operation operation" 
        + " WHERE operation.production.productionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate"
        + " AND operation.production.controlPoint.workCenter.costCenter.section= :section"
        + " GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(operation.production.productionDate,'%Y-%m')")
public List getMonthlyScheduleAdherenceBySection(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate, @Param("section") Section section);
```

the POJO to map the result:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MonthlyScheduleAdherence {

    String month;
    long actualTotal;
    long plannedTotal;
    long adherence;

}
```

With that I get:

```
[
    {
        month: "2017-02",
        actualTotal: 8640,
        plannedTotal: 10664,
        adherence: 81
    },
    {
        month: "2017-03",
        actualTotal: 8907,
        plannedTotal: 10352,
        adherence: 86
    },
    {
        month: "2017-04",
        actualTotal: 3224,
        plannedTotal: 4164,
        adherence: 77
    },
    {
        month: "2017-05",
        actualTotal: 8545,
        plannedTotal: 12435,
        adherence: 68
    }
]
```

And that is what I wanted.
I managed to successfully make this [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XutJU.png) with this data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sql function is available in JPQL. My JPA version is 1.11.9. Your DATE_FORMAT function not worked for me. I use function query for the group by day:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(ac) as count, function('date_format', max(ac.subscriptionStartDate), '%Y, %m, %d') as date FROM MyTable ac " +
        "WHERE ac.subscriptionStartDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY function('date_format', ac.subscriptionStartDate, '%Y, %m, %d')")
public List<Map<String,Object>> findRegisteredCustomersHistory(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

The result of the query is the list that records the number of records grouped by days in formatted form.

Sample result rows:

```
count: 3, date: 2019, 09, 10
count: 1, date: 2019, 09, 11
```

Simple function query in JPQL:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT function('date_format', s.date, '%Y, %m, %d') as date from Transactions s;")
```